# How to create a layout with fixed width and flexible height in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a layout(or panel) for tooltip that has a flexible height with fixed width like the image that I mentioned 
But in my xaml code both height and width is fixed !

```
<TextBox Name="mytxt" TextChanged="mytxt_TextChanged" Height="102"
                 SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"  >
            <TextBox.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Background="#e74c3c">
                    <StackPanel >
                        <Label Content="This is a error test for textbox with flat red background color"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToolTip>
            </TextBox.ToolTip>
        </TextBox>
```

[image: Tooltip image mentioned]

Comment: Are you using a custom style for that `TextBox`? Also, your question does not make sense. You are saying the "both height and width is fixed" yet you want a flexible height. Do you mean to say the program is always displaying a fixed height but your code does not have a fixed height?

Comment: Unfortunately my English is not well.
I'am saying I want to dynamically change the textbox height in the above xaml code if I fill the textbox content with lots of words it heights doesn't change anymore instead the width get increase . The picture that i mentioned has a fixed width and all changes is for height . Look at it . The first red block has 3 lines and more height than the second block that has 2 lines

Comment: Try using a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label` inside the `ToolTip` and enable `TextWrapping`. Set your fixed width and see if that helps. I am not in front of a computer with VS so I cannot test this, but that might work.

Comment: @DavidBentley yes. It works . tnx :)

Comment: I added my comment as an answer for you mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer since it solved your issue:

It looks like using the `Label` could be the issue. Replace the `Label` with a `TextBlock`. Then define the `TextWrapping` property to `true`. Set a fixed `width` and that will give you the desired behavior you are looking for.